# PowerMockito UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

Hello I have this PowerMockito test which throws anì UnfinishedStubbingException

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SuperHero.class)
public class SMSActionPresaInCaricoTest {

@Test
public void testExecute() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SuperHero.class);
    when(SuperHero.findSuperHero(anyString())).thenReturn(new SuperHero ());
    Action action = new Action();
    action.execute("", "");
}
```

The class SuperHero has a static method findSuperHero that returns an instance of SuperHero reading the data from DB.

I think the error is due to the fact that thenReturn is trying to return an instance of the mocked class SuperHero.

Is there a way to use PowerMockito with this scenario? Or is it some refactoring necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, cannot reproduce this one.

Here's my full test class, including all the imports:

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SuperHero.class)
public class SMSActionPresaInCaricoTest {

    @Test
    public void testExecute() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SuperHero.class);
        when(SuperHero.findSuperHero(anyString())).thenReturn(new SuperHero());
        assertNotNull(SuperHero.findSuperHero("Batman"));
    }
}
```

When I ran this test, it passed.

I didn't have your `SuperHero` class, so I used this one instead:

```
package com.example;

public class SuperHero {
    public static SuperHero findSuperHero(String name) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This method should have been mocked");
    }
}
```

I'm using PowerMockito 1.6.2, in case that helps.

Comment: "I didn't have your SuperHero class, so I used this one instead". This is also a good way to show your example works.

Comment: Thanks Luke for your input, I tried your sample and it works OK for me as well. So I investigated further and it seems that the problem with my SuperHero class is that it has a Spring @Configurable annotation which breaks the test case. I will investigate further and see whether I can find a solution.